# How to get an H1 using getelementby

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this code which I've been trying to fix for hours.

```
<div class="product_text">
<h2>empty</h2>
<h3>empty</h3>
<h1>THIS</h1>
</div>
```

I have tried everything: getElementsByTagName, getElementsByID, getElementsByClassName,

```
return $dom_document->getElementByTagName("h1")->nodeValue;;
```

But no success.

Comment: JavaScript ain't php. Use: `document.getElementsByTagName("h1");` Keep in mind that `getElementsByTagName` retuns an array of html elements, if any are found.

Comment: getElementsByTagName return an array have look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmqxdjqw/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
var h1s = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

alert(h1s[0].innerHTML);
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/hd7enb59/)